# Javascript - moment.js date object to unix string

Tags: javascript, date, unix, momentjs

I have some moment js date object.
The date in object is:

Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100

Im trying to do conversion to unix.
So im simply call date_start.unix();

But it returns for me: 1449097200, what means: 
Wed, 02 Dec 2015 23:00:00 GMT

So what i need to do to have exacly same date like in object? 
I see its 1 hour diffence... But i cant understand why it work like this.

Comment: It's the same datetime but not the same timezone. *Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 **GMT+0100*** is also *Wed, 02 Dec 2015 23:00:00 **GMT***.

Comment: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 23:00:00 GMT  ist the same as Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100...

Comment: I need exacly  Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 in unix time, because i calling mysql queries and looks from stats from 03.12.2015 00:00 03.12.2015 23:59 , so it means i need rows from whole day, how to change timezone?

Comment: Do you mean you need a _string_?

Comment: moment_date.unix() - returns 1449097200, I need: 1449100800

Comment: " i calling mysql queries and looks from stats from 03.12.2015 00:00 03.12.2015 23:59" - and what is the timezone *of that database*? This is crucial, because you seem to be using GMT in the database and GMT+1 in your code, which is the source of 1-hour offset.

Comment: Maybe you need to play with [local and UTC](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/)

Comment: Ok one more time: im using bootstrap rangepicker to get date ranges, for example today. When i do console.log(date), it shows Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 (moment.js)- which is great, because i need it!, but when i use date.unix() it returns string: 1449097200, I paste this string into http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php and i get one hour less, so its not today start, but yesterday 23:00 eu time. I need 00:00  what means day-begining.

Comment: That's the problem, right there: the converter says "23:00 (UTC)", but you are reading this as "23:00 EU time". This is a user error - "23:00 UTC" is "0:00 CET". London is not one hour in the past, even though it's now 13:54 there, and 14:54 here: both of these are *now*.

Comment: Ok, so how to fix it? how to change timezone? i tried change it in moment  timezone but doesent take any effect

Comment: If your database (with CET dates) is incorrectly running as GMT, `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1449097200),'CET','GMT'))` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`Thu Dec 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100` is the exact same moment in time as `Wed, 02 Dec 2015 23:00:00 GMT` is the exact same moment in time as unixtime `1449097200`.

There is no error: when it's 11 o'clock at night in London (**GMT**), it's already midnight in Brussels (**GMT+1**); both of these happen in the same moment.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it? I was try to change timezone, but it not works. 
for ex: date.tz('Australia/Sydney').unix();

Comment: To repeat my question, "what is the timezone of that database?" - I think your database may be running in GMT. Show us your database query, I believe the problem is actually *there*.

Answer (score 0):

I tired a lot of solutions here.
 - Change localisation in moment object (it was changed the date from moment was for ex in Asian time) then i tried use moment.unix() and again get same date and time!

What fixed my foroblem?
 - Just simply add +3600 to my time...
 - Make new utc date.

```
//First solution
var time = moment_start.unix() + 3600;

//Second solution
var time = new Date.UTC(y,m,d,h,m,s)/100; <--- This give me exacly same unix which i need!
```